# android app get user to resize a box

Tags: android

I am wanting to get a user to resize and reposition a box on the screen in the app (game).

I do not really care what the 'box' is (object type) as long as I can have it transparent to see a picture behind it and fire some code off it when the user touches that 'box'.

Comment: So what's your question...?

Comment: If your question is "how do I do this?", you should explain what you have tried and what problems you have encountered. You may wish to examine various [image cropping libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45), as they usually have this sort of bounding box.

Comment: Thanks yes the question IS how do I do this.

Comment: I this shall test and update the question.

Answer (score 0):

I shall try the cropping potential solution Alex mentioned and post what I get to work (may take a while...).
In case it is not obvious I am a newbie and did not have much of an idea where to start.